# Converting MXML to AS3: AreaSeries Click

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

-

I have a line of MXML for an AreaSeries in one of my Flex charts:

```
<mx:AreaSeries yField="A" displayName="A Model" click="clickResetChart(6)" buttonMode="true" mouseChildren="false" useHandCursor="true"/>
```

And I need to rewrite it into ActionScript.  I have all of it working except for the "click" function.  Could anyone tell me how to do it in AS?

```
var series1:AreaSeries = new AreaSeries();
series1.yField="A";
series1.displayName="A Model";
series1.buttonMode = true;
series1.useHandCursor = true;
series1.click???
```

series1.click does not exist... so what do I do?

### Much appreciated,

-Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
series1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    clickResetChart(6);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  And very prompt as well! :)